# #define (CLASS) in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction

I was looking at some coding done in a header file of a program installed on my PC & i found this :

```
# define A( CLASS )                                                  \
B(CLASS)                                                             \
void                *D(const C*to);
```

can anybody tell me what this means?
what are those slashes for & why hasnt all of this written in 1 line?
what does (CLASS) mean over here?
& why is there so much spacing done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslashes are there to "protect" the newline -- the preprocessor will throw away both the `\` and the newline when reading in the file, putting the entire thing on one logical line. (Well, it'll also emit `#line` markups so the compiler can generate decent error messages too.)

Someone thought that layout was more legible than this:

```
#define A(CLASS) B(CLASS) void *D(const C*to);
```

If you imagine that `B`, `D`, and `C` are probably replaced with something else in the file, it'll look a bit like this in the output:

```
Monkey(Simian) void *Bananas(const sticks *to);
```

It must have made more sense to them, as they wrote the macro, to instead "see" it like this:

```
Monkey(Simian)
void          *Bananas(const sticks *to);
```

I'm not sure it is an improvement (and I think I hate the style), but hopefully it makes sense now.

Comment: thanks a lot...can you answer my questions posted above as comments?
it would be very helpful

Comment: The `Monkey(Simian)` declares the new class `Monkey` to subclass `Simian`. I presume all of `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `CLASS` are defined elsewhere in the project.

Answer (score 5):

The `\` just append the statements on two different lines.
It is essential same as:

```
#define A(CLASS)  B(CLASS) void *D(const C*to);
```

This is done probably just for better readability.

Comment: thats ok but what about (CLASS) ?does it have to do anything with classes in c++?
& we usually do #define pi 3.142 or something like that... over here there are many more terms.
could you please tell me what is the relationship of A B C D?

Answer (score 2):

The slashes `\` means the definition of the macro continues on the next line. In the absense of `\`, the next line would not be considered as a part of the macro, because by default macro considers only one line on which `#define` is written.

It is analogous to `[contd...]` which many people often use in English language (especially on online forums), to indicate continuation.

Comment: thanks man :)
but can you tell me what does that #define do to A B C D?
i only know something like #define pi 3.142!
:(

Comment: @CAD_coding: I cannot tell that without knowing what exactly A B C D are, and your code doesn't tell me that.